# How to describe a feeding hand motion in the following context

Tags: creative-writing, phrasing

In context, a guy and a girl have a date, and in restaurant, they are having this moment, where girl feeds guy with "Say 'Ah!'".

**What is the best way to describe this motion from the guy's perspective?**

I'm not a native speaker, so the best I could think of was within the range of "*extended her arm with a spoon full of ice-cream to me*".

**Is there a better way to word such motion?**

EDIT:

Here is a context snippet in question:

> “Okay, that just won’t do! Here, say ‘Aah!’.”
>
> She **extended her arm to me with a spoon full of ice-cream**, slightly blushing for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is from his perspective, the arm motion can simply be implied. You could go as you are, the implied position of the two is opposite sides of the table, and simply say, ‘she fed me the spoonful of ice cream’.

Readers do not expect us to tell them how a person is walking, unless that detail is important. They assume the character is walking normally and we tell them why or where instead of how they walk.

If I were writing such a scene, I would have him notice a mischievous gleam in her eye, maybe wonder if she was going to smear it on his nose, but choose to trust her and lean forward a bit, closing his eyes. The sudden sweetness of the homemade strawberry ice cream on his tongue, he could taste the berries. etc.

Reached out would work too, but she might have to lean into the effort as there is a table between them and her partner is probably taller than she.

Your English is excellent.

Comment: Thank you. I have added an actual snippet of my context. Do you think, this is a part, where I can drop motion description entrely?

Comment: She reached toward me with the spoon full of ice cream, blushing, and I opened my mouth.

Comment: I like this one better.

Comment: It might be better to drop the motion description and use the intent instead - she fed me the ice cream. It is a bit more natural, but it depends on what you are trying to achieve. The context seems friendly and informal, so she fed me would seem more in tune with the tone

Comment: Yeah, either way, I'll need to go over both. But at least, I have some pointers now. Thanks.

Comment: If you choose to mention the movement, that could give you the opportunity to show some of her personality. She reached toward me with the spoon full of ice cream, blushing, and I opened my mouth. She paused, the spoon less than an inch from me, smiled and fed me the ice cream. She was right, it was the best I have had in years.